# mod_rewrite multiple ASPX urls

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

Moved a E-commerce store from a windows aspx server to a new cms on linux.  In order to maintain previous sitemap I need to redirect multiple aspx urls to a new aspx url. An example.

```
mysite.com/brand-material-style-large-blue.aspx  
mysite.com/brand-material-style-large-red.aspx  
mysite.com/brand-material-style-med-blue.aspx
```

all need to be redirected to mysite.com/brand-material-style.aspx

I've tried and tried, but cannot get the rewrite to work. Here's what I have now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} brand-material-style(.+)\.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand-material-style(.+)$ http://www.mysite.com/brand-material-style.aspx [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` installed and enabled in Apache?

Comment: mod_rewrite is indeed installed and enabled in Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a simple redirect?

```
RedirectMatch (.*)/brand-material-style(.+)\.aspx$ http://www.mysite.com/brand-material-style.aspx
```

Comment: Wow.  Gonzalo.  That works splendidly.  I have been way over thinking this.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't have any need for the RewriteRule...

```
RedirectMatch (.*)/brand-material-style(.+)\.aspx$ /brand-material-style.aspx [R=301,L]
```

You also don't need to specify the full URL, just the path to the file. And don't forget to add your attributes (for 301 compliance, etc.)